# Decode json array error

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am trying to decode a json with a loop that inserts all objects to my DB, the following is my php code, but i'm having the error:   Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in phptest.php on line 21

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    foreach($request as $key => $value) {
    $equip = $value['equipment'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contratos (equipo) VALUES ('$equip')";

}
}
```

I post the json with angular, the following code is my controller.js

```
$scope.continue = function(choices)
 {
     var data = $scope.choices;
     $http.post('php/phptest.php', data)
     .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);


   });
  };
```

And the json

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"choice1",
      "quantity":1,
      "equipment":"BLONG - F25",
      "teamvox":true,
      "plandatos":"D50"
  },
  {  
      "id":"choice2",
      "quantity":1,
      "equipment":"OUTERFONE - S17",
      "evidence":true,
      "mobictrl":true,
      "plandatos":"D100"
   }
]
```

Comment: You should only run your foreach once.

Comment: what does a var_dump of `$postdata` look like? Because I wonder if it is converting an object from js into post values and the posted data isn't json. [Because there appears to be nothing wrong with the json posted here.](https://3v4l.org/T1Nme)

Comment: Try `json_decode($postdata, true)` to force the result to be an associative array

Comment: Also, you have a potential SQL injection vector. Use parameter binding instead of query string interpolation

Answer (score 1):

You try to use access an object like an array inside your `foreach` loop. But [`json_decode`](https://secure.php.net/json_decode) makes an object. You can change this behaviour by passing `true` to the second argument.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    foreach($request as $key => $value) {
    $equip = $value['equipment'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contratos (equipo) VALUES ('$equip')";

}
}
```

Comment: I'd say it was not the `foreach` but the `$value['equipment']`. The original result would have been an array of `stdclass` objects so it should have been `$value->equipment`. Your solution fixes the issue though

Comment: @Phil Yeah, I meant `$value['equipment']`, `foreach` itself can work with both.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. In both OPs original code and your answer, `$request` is **always** an array. It's the items in the array that are different

Comment: Uh, yes. See that top line ~ `array(2)`

Comment: I think we're missing each other. `$value` itself in the loop is an object, thus throwing the error. Yes, `$request` itself is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$value->equipment` instead of `$value[equipment]` because the returned value is not not an array but a stdClass object.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the other elephant in the room; SQL injection vulnerability

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// make MySQLi throw exceptions
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `contratos` (`equipo`) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $equip);

foreach ($request as $data) {
    $equip = $data->equipment; // $data is a stdclass
    $stmt->execute();
}
```